# How do I mock react-router-dom using jest from a __mocks__ directory

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-router, jestjs

I have a test that is testing a provider, which is using react-router 6 `useLocation`

```json
"react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-beta.0",
```

It works fine when I mock in the file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Categories from './Categories';
import mockCategories from '../../__mocks__/mockCategories';
import ExpenditureProvider from '../../domains/Expenditure/ExpenditureProvider';

jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => {
  const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-router-dom');

  return {
    __esModule: true,
    ...originalModule,
    useNavigate: jest.fn(),
    useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ pathname: '/'}),
  };
});

describe('Categories', () => {
  test('should render Categories component', () => {
    const categories = render(
      <ExpenditureProvider>
        <Categories categories={mockCategories}/>
      </ExpenditureProvider>
      );
  });
});
```

but when I try to put this a `__mocks__` directory, This is the error I get

```
Error: Uncaught [Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.]
```

```js
// __mocks__/react-router-dom.js

const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-router-dom');
export default {
  __esModule: true,
  ...originalModule,
  useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ pathname: '/'}),
  useNavigate: jest.fn()
}
```

The mock file is in the root directory with node_modules

```
├── __mocks__
│   └── react-router-dom.js
├── node_modules
├── src
│
```

What I would like to do is only mock from the `__mocks__` directory because this mock is used in multiple tests

Comment: Please, update the question with the exact error message instead of vague *it doesn't work* statement, it may help users who have a similar problem.

Comment: @EstusFlask  This is the error I get Error: Uncaught [Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.], did you read the question?! I've moved it to make it clearer

Comment: Thanks. It wasn't clear that the error refers to the scenario where you used `__mocks__` rather than no mocks at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mock incorrectly exports module contents as `default` instead of `*`. There is no way to define `*` export dynamically with ES module `export` syntax. CommonJS export needs to be used instead, it works the same way as `jest.mock` return, `__esModule: true` makes it work like `*` ESM export:

```
const originalModule = jest.requireActual('react-router-dom');
module.exports = {
  __esModule: true,
  ...originalModule,
  useLocation: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ pathname: '/'}),
  useNavigate: jest.fn()
}
```

Comment: This was the only problem in the code you posted. As for the error, the mock is not picked up. Jest originally expects it alongside node_modules, like you did. If you use create-react-app project, move `__mocks__` to `src`, see https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7539

Comment: Thanks! this was the other half of the problem, Once I moved it into `src` it worked and as you stated it doesn't work with export default, thanks some much you are awesome